# If i have this in my styles.css whats the default font Roboto or Helventica Neue

Tags: css

If i have this in my styles.css whats the default font Roboto or Helventica Neue

body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Roboto` is available, `Roboto` will be your body font, `Helvetica Neue` is the first fallback.

> The browser will try to use the font you specified first, but if it doesn’t have that font available, it will keep going down that list.

If `Helvetica Neue` also fails, your font will be whatever your browser has to offer for the generic keyword `sans-serif`

Answer (score 0):

**font-family priorities are from left to right.**

So if Roboto is available it's used.
If not and Helvetica Neue is available then it's used.

If nether are available it defaults to a generic sans-serif font.

So Roboto -> Helvetica Neue -> Sans-Serif